# Generate database schema diagram from PostgreSQL DDL files

Tags: database, diagram, postgresql

I'm looking for online/offline software that accepts a SQL file with a `CREATE TABLE` statement as input and generates a database schema diagram like one below:

[image]

I did some research and I know there's plenty of software that can connect to a database and generate the diagram. It's not possible to connect to a database in my case - all I have are DDL files (more than 1000). I know DBeaver provides such functionality but for one table at a time - I'm looking for a automated solution.

EDIT:
Software that I'm looking for should be preferably open-sourced or at least have a free trial version. It must fully support PostgreSQL data structures. The platform it should run on is Windows 10.

Comment: What OS should the software run on? How much may it cost? What "SQL dialects" must it support (e.g. PostgreSQL has a data type "serial", which is unknown to MySQL/Oracle; Oracle has "varchar2" which the other two don't know, and so on; you wouldn't want the software to "crash" on such things)?

Comment: creating an aesthetic layout or appropriate layout is another matter. What do you prefer?  (few crossings of PK/FK relationships as possible; putting  tables with many columns next to each other,...)